# Pythonic way to match up timestamps in list of objects

Tags: python

I have two lists, each of which contain objects that have a property `gps_seconds`.

There will be a period of time where the `gps_seconds` property lines up, and I would like to trim the two list down so that I have separate lists with common timestamps.

For example in list `A` the objects I might have `gps_seconds` parameters:

```
99.8
99.9
100.0
100.1
100.2
```

List `B` might be have:

```
99.9
100.0
100.1
100.2
100.3
```

In this case I would like to remove the first entry from `A` and the final entry from `B` to ensure that the timestamps of both lists match up properly.

I have attempted a rather inelegant method of my own but it feels like there might be a pythonic way to do this quickly that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
set1 = set([99.8, 99.9, 100.0, 100.1, 100.2])
set2 = set([99.9, 100.0, 100.1, 100.2, 100.3])
res = set1 & set2
print res
```

`Operator &` on sets returns the intersection of the sets.

Comment: Thanks, this now forms the basis for my solution. I've now got to deal with the fact that one clock seems to drift relative to the other!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with list comprehension but using `in` for this might not be the fastest way...

```
list1 = [99.8,
99.9,
100.0,
100.1,
100.2]

list2 = [99.9,
100.0,
100.1,
100.2,
100.3]

[a for a in [b for b in list1 if b in list2] if a in list1]
```

which returns

```
[99.9, 100.0, 100.1, 100.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets:

```
>>> list_A = [99.8, 99.9, 100.0, 100.1, 100.2]
>>> list_B = [99.9, 100.0, 100.1, 100.2, 100.3]
>>> sorted(set(list_A).intersection(list_B))
[99.9, 100.0, 100.1, 100.2]
```

Here I assume that the timestamps will always be ascending, and therefore sorting the intersection of the two sets should be valid.